# Open TCL pipeline to cygwin running terminal

Tags: cygwin, tcl, putty, tty

So i'm running a TCL program in Windows. Is there any way to write directly to my running Cygwin terminal? Assuming my TCL workspace is currently in C:\workspace and cygwin installation is C:\cygwin\ and windows cannot see private Cygwin files for example inside /dev/pty0 .

Answer (score 0):

Without having a copy of Cygwin handy to check, I can't be certain, but I understood that files in C:\cygwin were visible to both Windows and the Cygwin terminal. So try writing to a directory under C:\cygwin from your TCL program. Then you should be able to read and display that file from Cygwin.

Alternatively, isn't Cygwin able to see the entire Windows file system, as per [this](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.it/2011/12/cygwin-access-windows-disk-directories.html) example?

Comment: I have no problem seeing files from either Cygwin or Windows. I am calling from the Cygwin terminal, a batch that runs a program. How can that program running in the background (program which uses the TCL language) write something back to my Cygwin terminal, which i am currently in ? It isn't even a problem of TCL since i can exec from tcl another program, it's a problem of a Windows program inserting something into my cygwin terminal.

Comment: As I said, from TCL you can write to a file, and have your Cygwin batch program read that file.

Comment: i need it to write to a terminal